# Google map iframe into wordpress theme

Tags: google-maps

I have embedded a Google Map iframe in my theme and I'm trying to center a Google Map location in the middle of the map. All works fine except that my location is always shown to the upper left corner not the center

This is my website: http://tommelopp.no/kontakt/

The pop up is made using javascript to center it. Happy for all suggestions, tips or answers :)

Comment: Off topic. Please ask google-maps Qs on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled some more and found out that the problem was that the `<div>` element containing the iframe was `display:none;` in my css.

My solution to this problem was to insert the iframe using jquery after i change the display type to block (also using jquery).

Hope this helps someone else. Sorry for posting this in the wrong place...

Answer (score 1):

I've used it like this and it works well ;-)

```
$(".div").html("<iframe width='850' height='450' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://yourlocation.com'></iframe>");  
$(".div").css("display","block");
```